# removing large file in git repository

Tags: git

In our repository, long time ago, somebody added an Access DB which was quite large. That DB meanwhile got removed but obviously pollutes the history. I run git-sizer and got this:

```
[4]  f660c63e4d46e5b78d384b08814b9ea20f164952 (ec7e0ee38cd178cbe634e0dbddb3b2e41749f434:ad_hoc/DM_Analyse/202011221_Output.accdb)
```

Now all my attemts to remove it with filter branch failed. Would someone have an idea, how to remove it? I guess, part of the problem is the fact, that the file exists only in the branch (which also got removed meanwhile).

I run:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch ad_hoc/DM_Analyse/202011221_Output.accdb' --prune-empty -f -- --all
```

which rewrote the history but nevertheless the file remains? I also did search for the file and tried to find out, which commit was invoved in this file but funny enough, I couldn't find such a commit???

Comment: You might want to try running `git gc` or similar. But before that, you might want to make sure there is no reference to that file (also not in any remote).

Comment: Obviousl I did git gc but the file keeps showing up in the history.

Comment: In which history? `git filter-branch` makes backups of the branches, which keeps the original history alive. Make a clone to a new directory and check there.

Comment: I did in fact but it didn't help